# How to gain Reddit API access token?

Tags: curl, oauth, oauth-2.0, reddit

I have been using this as a resource: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example

I am referencing the Curl Example to acquire a token.

Here is exactly what I am running in terminal:

`curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=password&username=ollynov14@password=myrealpassword' --user 'jRje7BA55aycvA:myrealsecret' https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token`

(of course I have my actual secret and password in those fields above)

and I am getting the following error: 
`{"message": "Too Many Requests", "error": 429}`
(I have been getting this error from the start so I don't think it actually has to do with how many times I've run this curl)

I just recently signed up for Reddit a couple hours ago in case that makes a difference...

Does anyone have an idea why I may not be getting the access token from the Reddit API? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to include "User agent". Please add an option "-A" to curl. And for your curl code, 'grant_type=password&username=ollynov14@password=myrealpassword' is wrong. Please change "@" to "&".

```
curl -X POST -A 'User agent' -d 'grant_type=password&username=ollynov14&password=myrealpassword' --user 'jRje7BA55aycvA:myrealsecret' https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token
```

Using above command, following result can be got.

> {"access_token": "#####", "token_type": "bearer", "expires_in": 3600, "scope": "*"}

Comment: Thanks a lot. The documentation was wrong, it had the "@" instead of the "&" (but I probably should have found that myself). And yes, I saw multiple mentions of including the user agent. The user agent can be anything right? (better to be descriptive, but not strictly necessary right?)

Comment: You can use various user agents. But very simple one may not be able to use. And I could get access token even when I removed the option of "-X POST". It can get by "GET".

Comment: @Tanaike I'm trying your solution but it is giving me error 
{"error_description": "Only script apps may use password auth", "error": "unauthorized_client"}

Comment: @Null Pointer Thank you for your comment. I tried the curl command of my answer. But in my environment, no error occurs. I could retrieve access token by both POST and GET method. I'm sorry. If the error occurs in your environment, can you post it with the detail information as a new question?